# Ruby On rails In iPhone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a app which uses a webservice to store and to retrieve data. We are using a Ruby On Rails webservice. We're not able to use post Method to store data on Ruby On rails Webservice. Does anybody have an idea on how to send request to save data to the server. How to access ruby on rails web service????? Any help will be appreciated!!!!!!

Comment: Any other option that you found better ?

Answer (score 0):

Since RoR is Rest conform you can use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) to get/post your data.

> RestKit is a Cocoa framework for interacting with RESTful web services in Objective C on iOS and Mac OS X. It provides a set of primitives for interacting with web services wrapping GET, POST, PUT and DELETE HTTP verbs behind a clean, simple interface. RestKit also provides a system for modeling remote resources by mapping them from JSON (or XML) payloads back into local domain objects. Object mapping functions with normal NSObject derived classes with properties. There is also an object mapping implementation included that provides a Core Data backed store for persisting objects loaded from the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose either [rc-tool](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/restclient-tool/downloads/list) or [RestClient](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2008/3/9/rest_client/)